# diagonalizability of endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $f:V\to V$ an endomorphism with a minimal polynomial $(X − \lambda)(X − \mu)$.
Prove that $\operatorname{Im}f(f − \lambda\operatorname{id}) \subset V_{\mu}$.
 I have no idea how.

Comment: What does Imf mean? What is $V\mu$?

Comment: what is $f(f-\lambda id)$??? What is $V\mu$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Those are standard notations in linear algebra. $\;V_\mu\;$ usually denotes the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $\;\mu\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio When I asked it was $V\mu$, not  $V_\mu$...

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*. Cayley–Hamilton says $(f - μI)(f - λI) = 0$, hence $f(f - λI) = μI(f - λI)$ for $I = \mathrm{id}_V$.

Comment: I'd use $\;(f-\lambda I)\;$ for clarity, instead of that annoying $\;\lambda id_V\;$ ...+1

Comment: @DonAntonio Hm. To me, the only annoying bit about $\mathrm{id}_V$ is that it takes longer to tex out. Do you find it annoying to read? How so?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. In particular because the $\;\lambda\;$, or the $\;\mu\;$ ,  and the "i" in id$_V\;$ are too close. Within this discussion, everybody would understand what $\;I\;$ stands for.

Comment: @DonAntonio Hm, I’ll give it a try.